# How to renew my AAD session using adal-angular5?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I'm using the [adal-angular5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-angular5) v1.0.36 client library to authenticate my web application to Azure Active Directory.

The thing is that my session lasts 1 hour (the default expiration time) and I'd like to "renew" it silently for the user once it has expired; i.e. without having to ask the user for the credentials again or logging out and then login again (which would cause work loss for the user).

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Haven't used the Angular module, but technically that should handle token renewal silently for you, unless you are caching the token it gives you somewhere (which you should not do). And then if ADAL cannot renew the token silently, you have to do interactive authentication.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the user have an active session with Azure AD, ADAL JS does it automatically for you. ADAL JS examines the projected expiration of the existing token (in the cache) and if the token is about to expire, it uses an invisible iFrame to send a new token (renewal) request to Azure AD.

Please choose MSAL over ADAL and here is the sample  for [angular](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-angular/)  using MSAL.

Please refer the link for [migration of ADAL to MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-migration)